# Swift array and dictionary immutability

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift

What is the intended design of swift's 'Immutable Arrays' allow update operation. 
Whereas, 'Immutable Dictionaries' alone exempted from this particular behavior. Your thoughts...

```
let newArray = ["1","3","4"] // Immutable <String> array 'newArray'
newArray[1]="2"//update index 1 with the value 2 (no error)
newArray[2]="3"//update index 2 with the value 3 (no error)

let newDictionary = [1 : "one", 2 : "third"]//Immutable <Int,String> Dictionary 'newDictionary'
newDictionary[2] = "second" // update 2 keyed value by "third" (throws error)
```

1. Why Immutable Arrays alone allowing update operation, Why Immutable Dictionary not allowed for update operation.
2. In the documentation it's been written, For the optimal performance sake, specify the fixed sized arrays as immutable(constant) arrays. What are the optimal things performed on this immutable arrays. Thoughts....

Comment: Why? why?? only apple knows. Language is designed like that. They may have there own reasons

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary and Array copy value when we use it

From Swift book

Array:

> “For arrays, copying only takes place when you perform an action that has the potential to modify the length of the array. ”

So as long as you dont change the size of array, the constant variable still use the same size and our constant still point at old value.

Dictionary:

> “Whenever you assign a Dictionary instance to a constant or variable, or pass a Dictionary instance as an argument to a function or method call, the dictionary is copied at the point that the assignment or call takes place.”

So for dictionary, every time you do something with it, it copy itself and assign back to variable. That breaks the rule of `let`

This is a prove of Dictionary copying

```
class Test {
    var newDictionary: Dictionary<Int,String> = [:] {
        didSet {
            println("reset")
        }
    }

    func test() {
        newDictionary = [1 : "one", 2 : "third"]
        newDictionary[2] = "second"
    }
}

Test().test()
```

Output is

```
reset
reset
```

EDIT: Even array also call didSet when update value. This cannot prove what happen inside, only Apple knows

Comment: I think, your this "So for dictionary, every time you do something with it, it copy itself and assign back to variable. That breaks the rule of let" line, has something that I wanted. Could you please elaborate if you're 100% sure about it.

Comment: will update the answer

Comment: arrays behave the same as the didSet called when you try to update an element.

Comment: So that mean we cannot inspect what exactly happen underlying and we cannot see the pointer too, only apple knows :|